# Open password protected Excel file, using powershell single line command

Tags: powershell

I am trying to open a password protected excel file using CMD and I think powershell is the only option.

I have tried the below, which opens the excel document, but does't seem to pass the password correctly.

I would be grateful if someone could let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
powershell $path="C:\Path\To\File\Test.xlsx" ; $password="12345" ; $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application ; $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($path,$false,$false,5,$password) ; $excel.Visible = $true
```

Comment: You are using Lotus 123 format.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat?force_isolation=true

Comment: There may of been a bug a long time ago where you needed to use Lotus 123 mode to work with passwords.  It may have been fixed.  The format is the 4th parameter in the open. See following : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/password-protecting-individual-worksheets-in-excel-so-each/m-p/1566266?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I got this to work from command line:

```
powershell -Command "$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application;$Excel.Visible = $true;$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\Path\To\File\Test.xlsx',0,$false,5,'12345')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use cmd for this and not straight away in PowerShell?

The 4th parameter on the WorkBooks.Open() method is called `Format` and determines the delimiter character for the file.
Since you are opening not a text delimited file, but a xlsx file, you must **omit** that parameter.

Here's the code written out in several lines for better readability:

```
$path          = "C:\Path\To\File\Test.xlsx"
$password      = "12345"
$excel         = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $true

# note that for any variant parameter you wish to omit, you use [type]::Missing
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($path, $false, $false, [type]::Missing, $password)
```

<sup>From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbooks.Open) : *"If Microsoft Excel opens a **text file**, this argument specifies the delimiter character. If this argument is omitted, the current delimiter is used."*</sup>

Comment: @Vanburen Thanks for the feedback. If you feel my answer solved your problem, please accept it so it can be found easier by others with a similar problem. You can see in the [tour] how you can mark a question 'solved'

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have to use CMD as I am calling from a separate program that uses CMD by default, this is also why I need to keep the command on a single line. I tried the above as a single line `powershell $path = "C:\Path\To\File\Test.xlsx" ; $password = "12345"; $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application; $excel.Visible = $true ; $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($path, $false, $false, [type]::Missing, $password)`

Comment: but got "12345 : The term
'12345' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."